# Deep Learning CNN MINST TensorFlow applied to my own images

Tags: deep-learning

I'm new in Deep Learning and I started with the TenserFlow tutorials (The beginner one and the expert one).In both of them, the data is imported at the beginning with these 2 lines : 
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
 `mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)`

I would like to use this neural network on my own images. I have 100 000 images et a fileLabel.txt giving the labels for each image in order by column. Is there a way to change these two lines or a few others to import my images without breaking all the code ? I really don't see how to do that, I have the impression that the structure `mnist` is specific to the images of the tutorial.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to your question is yes - its possible. You don't need to break any code IF your data is also similar to MNIST data with 10 labels and well organized.

Assuming that is not the case, then you need to organize your input data so that you can define (create) your model.

Organizing of your input data includes

- Having consistent image sizes (for example MNIST is 28x28 pixel images)
- Labeling of your images (for example MNIST has 10 labels - 0 to 9)
- Finally how you intend to split your data (for example MNIST data is split into three parts: 55,000 data points of training data (mnist.train), 10,000 points of test data (mnist.test), and 5,000 points of validation data (mnist.validation).

Once you organize your input data, then you read your data by writing a small function like read_images that does something like

```
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
....
```

Then assuming you want to "label" ahead of time similar to MNIST data, you can store them in a file and read them in your program.

After that, you would have to populate the tf.train.string_input_producer() with a list of strings containing the filename and the label.

....

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Indeed, I have a different number of labels, 36 to be precise (letters + digits = 26 + 10)
I have organized it as it is done for MNIST data. 

May I ask you more details about the function reading the data ? What is the filename_queue ?

Comment: Oh that's just a variable - a queue node that holds your filenames (of images). So, you would do something like `filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['DIR_to_your_image_files'])` . For more details on how to do this, please check - [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data)

Comment: (time expired for the previous comment - so adding one more comment) For more details on how to do this, please check - [Tensorflow documentation on reading_data (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) and [This blog about reading multiple images] (https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1033514/Example-loading-multiple-JPEG-files-with) - Hope this was helpful, @KB303.